# CSS Max-Width Media Query Unexpected Behavior

Tags: css

I have used max-width and min-width media queries to make my site responsive without any problems for years. But today I noticed an odd behavior: the max-width rule stopped working for the screen width in the limit. For example If I'm changing color to blue at 899px, it only starts changing it at 898 px.

I'm not sure where the problem is, I tested in multiple browsers, local and production and the result is the same. I even made a code pen and the max-width value keeps getting ignored: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzWWqd

```
body { background-color: yellow; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {
    body { background-color: blue; }
}
```

The result of that CSS is that the screen is yellow at 899px, where it shouldn't be, it should be blue.

Could this be related to my screen resolution? The only thing I changed was my computer screen. I'm using Windows 10 in a 1440p screen. Before I had windows 10 in a 1080p screen.

Comment: See if the change in hardware caused Windows to change your display scaling settings to compensate. (Unlikely, but worth a look anyway. You'll find scaling settings in the same place as resolution.)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes! That was the problem. I changed Windows 10 scaling back to 100% and now the Media Query works as expected... Weird that windows scaling produces this kinds of problem and I couldn't find any info about this. 
Thank you!